# How to find the matrix of the transformation relative to the basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $T:P_2\to P_2$ be the linear operator defined by
$$T(a+bx+cx^2)=(3a+2b+4c)+(2a+2c)x+(4a+2b+3c)x^2$$
Find the matrix of the transformation $T$ relative to the basis $B=\{1,x,x^2\}$.

Comment: Write as column vectors the coordinates of $T(1), T(x)$ and $T(x^2)$ in basis $\mathcal B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
\begin{align*}
e_1(t) &= 1 & e_2(t) &= t & e_3(t) &= t^2
\end{align*}
and note that $\beta=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is a basis for $P_2$. Note that
\begin{array}{lclclclclclc}
T(e_1) & = & \color{red}3\,e_1&+&\color{green}2\,e_2&+&\color{blue}4\,e_3\\
T(e_2) & = & \color{red}2\,e_1&+&\color{green}0\,e_2&+&\color{blue}2\,e_3\\
T(e_3) & = & \color{red}4\,e_1&+&\color{green}2\,e_2&+&\color{blue}3\,e_3
\end{array}
The matrix of $T$ relative to the basis $\beta$ is then
$$
[T]_\beta^\beta=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}3 & \color{red}2 & \color{red}4 \\
\color{green}{2} & \color{green}0 & \color{green}2 \\
\color{blue}4 & \color{blue}2 & \color{blue}3
\end{bmatrix}
$$